# Sending Data to Javascript from Rails (Forms)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I am storing some data in Rails which I then access from Javascript. (I am using the [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) to do so). When I hardcode a string value (for gon) in the controller, it works fine, and I can access this data from javascript:

```
#set in rails, available in JS
gon.stuff = { "1" => "one stuff\n print 'hi'.. ",
          "2" => "two stuff\n print 'by' "}
```

However, when I submit the data through a Rails form (to Post's 'stuff' column) , it ends up 'over-stringified', so it shows up in Javascript as a complete string:

post.stuff text_area:

```
 { "1" => "stuff about one\n more stuff.. ",
          "2" => "two stuff\n more stuff"}
```

setup data in rails:

```
 gon.stuff = @post.stuff
```

JS data ends up as complete string:

```
"{ "1" => "stuff about one\n more stuff.. ",
              "2" => "two stuff\n more stuff"}"
```

How do I turn it from a string into accessible data? Also, should I be storing and accessing the data in a different manner?

Comment: Try submitting it as a Hash?

Hash[@post.stuff]

Comment: I don't believe serializing the stuff column will have the desired effect. I believe that you're passing the wrong data type to gon so it is just running an arbitrary .to_s on the input.

Comment: @MatthewGraves How do I submit it differently than all the other form elements?

Comment: No, gon is definitely expecting a hash and post.stuff is not a hash, so converting post.stuff to a hash should solve your problem. Either Hash[@post.stuff]

Comment: Please see my answer now. I assume that @post.stuff is actually json submitted via post?