# How do I turn a string into a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I have a string like this:

```
//string
" { "1" => "one stuff\n print 'hi'.. ",
          "2" => "two stuff\n print 'by' "} "
```

How do I turn it into a a JSON object so I can access its parts with e.g. `string["1"]` ?

(Follow-up to
[Sending Data to Javascript from Rails (Forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303824/sending-data-to-javascript-from-rails-forms) )

Comment: JSON *is* a string. If you want to access its parts, you need to convert it from JSON into a native object structure. If you're talking about doing this in JavaScript, then you'd do `var obj=JSON.parse(my_json_string);`

Comment: @CrazyTrain don't you mean `JSON.stringify(my_json_string);`?

Comment: @am-rails... did you think about replacing the `=>` character to `:` and then parse it as json?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: No, if it's a string formatted as JSON, then it needs to be parsed into the native object structures of the programming language in question to be able to access its individual members. Unless I misunderstand the question, OP is sending JSON from a Ruby on Rails app to a JavaScript client.

Comment: ["one stuff\n print 'hi'.. ", "two stuff\n print 'by' "]

Comment: JSON.parse works once I replaced the `=>` to `:` and the newlines to `/n`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're rendering it appropriately in rails. The string you listed isn't valid javascript (it's using the ruby hashrocket syntax rather than JSON hash syntax):

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        str = ' { "1": "one stuff\n print \'hi\'.. ", "2": "two stuff\n print \'bye\' "} '
        render json: str
      end
    end
  end
end
```

or much better (relying on rails to build the json for you from a ruby hash):

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        obj = {1 => "one stuff\n print 'hi'", 2 => "two stuff\n print 'bye'" }
        render json: obj
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then fetch the json at `/things.json` assuming this is hooked up in your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: Thanks. The string comes from a Rails form, so I can make the text submitted there have `:` instead of `=>` (like in your first answer) but I don't have it as an object as required in the second answer, it comes out of the form as a string.

Comment: Be very careful about serving up content to browsers that comes from user input. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss in particular.

Comment: that may be an issue in the future, but right now users don't have access to those forms.